# Linq Query Where clause not working correctly

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm having trouble with a linq query. the query works fine with no errors but I am using a where clause for entries greater than a certain date and it does not work.

the date from `r.Start Date` is a date datatype from sql and dateAndTime is shown

```
  var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
  var querythpshols = (from r in db.HolidayRequestForms
                             where (r.StartDate) >= dateAndTime 
                             group r by r.MonthOfHoliday into g
                             select new { 
                                Value = g.Key, 
                                Count = g.Sum(h => h.HoursTaken), 
                                MonthName = g.Select(d => d.MonthOfHoliday) 
                             });

  var resultthpshols = querythpshols.ToList();
```

Any help on this would be appreciated on this. 
As of now, I get entires but the where clause is not applied

SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm](
[RequestID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[StartDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[FinishDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[HoursTaken] [decimal](7, 3) NOT NULL,
[Comments] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[YearCreated] [int] NOT NULL,
[MonthCreated] [int] NOT NULL,
[DayCreated] [int] NOT NULL,
[YearOfHoliday]  AS (datepart(year,[StartDate])),
[Approved] [bit] NULL,
[SubmittedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ApprovedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[WorkWeek]  AS ((datepart(dayofyear,(datediff(day,(0),[StartDate])/(7))*(7)+(3))+(6))/(7)),
[MonthOfHoliday]  AS (datepart(month,[StartDate])),
[MonthOfHolidayName]  AS (datename(month,[StartDate])),
```

Comment: Does not work as in you get wrong entries? No entries?

Comment: Sorry, I get the entries but the where clause is not applied

Comment: This code will certainly use the where-clause, so there is something else going on. Can you provide example data you are querying?

Comment: @Esko I've added the Sql table, would it be a problem with date formats?

Comment: Can you give example of StartDate's that you get that you did not expect. And also the value of `dateAndTime `

Comment: It's displaying all values, completely ignoring the where clause. the value of `dateAndTime`  is `22/03/2019 09:09:10`

Comment: Then an example of a date of a entrie it's returning that it shouldn't is  `[1] = {05/03/2019 00:00:00}}`

Comment: I got it solved. The error was futher down the code in google charts so I guess the query is good